# How to open a div with button click and closing all other divs at the same time in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I show a specific div element with a button click and close **all** other elements at the same time in jQuery?

For example, I tired:

```js
   $('.button').each(function(i) {
    $(this).click(function() { 
            $('.details').eq(i).slideToggle("slow")
            $('.button').eq(i);
        });
    });
```

```css
.details {
  background: grey;
  display: none;
}

.is-open {
  display: block;
}

<!-- language: lang-html -->

<button id="button0" class="button">button 1</button>
<button id="button1" class="button">button 2</button>
<button id="button2" class="button">button 3</button>

<div class="details" id="details0">
  <h1>Details Person 1</h1>
</div>

<div class="details" id="details1">
  <h1>Details Person 2</h1>
</div>

<div class="details" id="details2">
  <h1>Details Person 3</h1>
</div>
```

But this only toggles one elements without closing the others. But I want to close every opened element by clicking the one which isn't opened already.

I tried it with the suggested siblings() method but this did not apply for my case because I have my button elements separated from the button elements.

What is the best solution to achieve such an effect described above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you adjust your HTML to have [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) where each button data-id corresponds to a data-id on a details element it makes it much simpler.

```js
// Use event delegation to listen to events from the buttons
$(document).on('click', 'button', handleClick)

function handleClick() {

  // Grab the id from the button
  const id = $(this).data('id');

  // Remove all the `show` classes from the details elements
  $('.details').removeClass('show');

  // And then add that class back on to the details element
  // that corresponds to the id
  $(`.details[data-id=${id}]`).addClass('show');
}
```

```css
.details { background: grey; display: none; }
.show { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button data-id="1">button 1</button>
<button data-id="2">button 2</button>
<button data-id="3">button 3</button>

<div class="details" data-id="1">
  <h1>Details Person 1</h1>
</div>

<div class="details" data-id="2">
  <h1>Details Person 2</h1>
</div>

<div class="details" data-id="3">
  <h1>Details Person 3</h1>
</div>
```

Additional documentation

- [Event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)
- [Template/string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to implement the tab?
https://jqueryui.com/tabs/

```js
$('.button').each(function (i) {
  $(this).click(function () {
    $('.details').eq(i).show("slow").siblings('.details').hide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```js
$('.button').each( function(index,button){
        //console.log(button.outerHTML);
    $(button).click(function(){
        let  id=this.id.replace("button","");
      $(".details").hide()
      $("#details"+id).show();
    })
});
```

```css
.details {
  background: grey;
  display: none;
}

.is-open {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="button0" class="button">button 1</button>
<button id="button1" class="button">button 2</button>
<button id="button2" class="button">button 3</button>

<div class="details" id="details0">
  <h1>Details Person 1</h1>
</div>

<div class="details" id="details1">
  <h1>Details Person 2</h1>
</div>

<div class="details" id="details2">
  <h1>Details Person 3</h1>
</div>
```